# Uploading binary files (<1GB) to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: database, postgresql, binaryfiles, psql

I am trying to upload binary files to a postgres database.  This is basically the situation:

1. There exists a set of files.
2. The files are uploaded to the database with metadata such as the file's name, size, creation date, modification date, path.
3. Thereafter, a user can query the metadata and download the set of files that are in the query results.

I'm not sure how to do this in postgres.  I am using the psql shell on Windows.  Can anyone advise?

Comment: You'll have to write a program for this. It matters if you want to use `bytea` or Large Objects. Don't even try to store objects that come close to 1GB.

Comment: As Laurenz says, you can't do this using psql, because you can't insert the binary data using psql. You need a program which has bindings for the ByteA type (every modern programming language with a PostgreSQL driver should have that).